# How to remove extra space in ImageView taken in scroll view with the Aspect Fit?

Tags: ios, swift

I have UIImageView in the Scroll View, I set content mode of image view is aspect fit. When I select an image from gallery then it shows blank space in the above and bottom of the image but I want the removed empty space of image in the scroll view.

Comment: can you please attach the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to keep same aspect ratio for image size and image view.

- If your image is in app bundle then check its aspect ration and give
  same aspect ratio constraint to image view from storyboard.
- if your image is dynamic i.e. coming from api then give height
  constraint to it (imageViewHeight). and change it as per image aspect
  ratio.

  ```
  let height =  (imageView.frame.width * image.size.height) /  image.size.width

  imageViewHeight.constant = height
  ```

imageViewHeight is height constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Hook the height constraint of the imageView

```
let h =  (imageView.frame.width * img.size.height) /  img.size.width
imageViewHCon.constant = h
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Above you apply the same aspect ratio to the imageView , so there will be no blank around it